# How to adjust contentInset of UIScrollView quietly while dragging

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

To make some kind of effect, I would like to adjust the `contentInset` of `UIScrollView` while the user drags the `scrollView` base on some formula, but I don't want the user to be aware of the change of `contentInset`.

However, I found out that when I change the `contentInset`, the content of `scrollView` jump to another place, which results in a bad UI.

If I adjust `contentOffset` of the `scrollView` to keep the content, the content of `scrollView` will also flash quickly. It seems like that the content jump up and down in a flash.

Are there any ways to adjust `contentInset` of `UIScrollView` while dragging?

Comment: Hi, I can't see why you would like to do that. Can you please tell what is the effect you want to achieve? can you elaborate on this? I think there must be a better solution than changing the contentInset while scrolling. Thanks anyway